# WinRT-XAML Alternative to a grid of TextBox

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a grid of TextBox inside a Border with the content binded like so

```
<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="29.333" Text="{Binding TextArray[0][0], Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
</Border>
<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="29.333" Text="{Binding TextArray[0][1], Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
</Border>
<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" Grid.Column="2">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="29.333" Text="{Binding TextArray[0][2], Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
</Border>
<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="29.333" Text="{Binding TextArray[1][0], Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
</Border>
<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="29.333" Text="{Binding TextArray[1][1], Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
</Border>
<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="29.333" Text="{Binding TextArray[1][2], Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
</Border>
<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="29.333" Text="{Binding TextArray[2][0], Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
</Border>
<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="29.333" Text="{Binding TextArray[2][1], Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
</Border>
<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="29.333" Text="{Binding TextArray[2][2], Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
</Border>
```

This is fine for a small grid, but there would a lot of copy pasting and replacing values for a big grid. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "a grid of TextBox inside a Border". I only see a TextBlock inside Border elements. Post your grid xaml code.

Comment: It's more of a grid of Border each with a TextBlock inside since there is no way to vertical align the text in a TextBlock. I edit the post to include the whole 3x3 grid.

Comment: You can programatically add the textblock elements to the grid. [Like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583954/filling-grid-with-textboxes-programmatically-in-wpf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy solution, stop using those crazy TextArrays. Let's pretend you really do have an array like you are showing. Why not make your life easier?

Start with simplifying your data!

```
string[][] _Data = new[] 
    { 
        new string[] { "A", "B", "C" }, 
        new string[] { "1", "2", "3" } 
    };
var _NewData =
    from d in _Data
    select new
    {
        One = d[0],
        Two = d[1],
        Three = d[2]
    };
this.DataContext = _NewData;
```

Then you can simplify your XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="600">

                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="29.333" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- first record -->
                    <Border Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding One}" />
                    </Border>

                    <!-- second record -->
                    <Border Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Two}" />
                    </Border>

                    <!-- third record -->
                    <Border Grid.Column="2">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Three}" />
                    </Border>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Now there is ZERO redundancy. The XAML was meant to be used.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use, DataGrid for WinRT - there are alot of datagrid's available for WinRT from Third Party something like Syncfusion Offers you can check here.

http://darkcore.in/getting-started-in-syncfusions-datagrid-sfdatagrid-for-winrt/